# Error: Could not find or load main class ... in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I knew there are similar question posted already but none of it helped in resolving my issue. Currently I am working on a Scala project using eclipse.

Issue 1 : Unable to get Run As -> Scala application
Issue 2: When I run my program through Run Configurations, getting the following error

> Error: Could not find or load main class NewStreaming

Code :

```
src/main/scala/NewStreaming.scala

object NewStreaming {

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

...
...
}}
```

Issue 3: Able to do "mvn package", but when I execute the jar in hdp,  with spark-submit, getting the following exception

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NewStreaming

Comment: What are your spark-submit options?

Comment: @AndreiT. : spark-submit  --class NewStreaming  /kafkaProj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to do a Rebuild / Clean of your Project? :)

I didn't use eclipse since a while. But I remember I got a problem of that kind.

Comment: Well, it can happen for many reasons.. Do you use some libs? Do you move your project directory recently?